# Sum column rows where date == specific date in C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio, charts

We have a date column in an database table. We need to check if the date occurs multiple times and add the sum of another column, called 'hours_remaining'.

For example on 30/11/2017 we have two tasks with 3 and 4 in the 'hours_remaining' column. We need to sum these values and plot to a Visual Studio chart.

Currently it plots the two values separately on the chart.[image: Chart example]

```
con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SprintTask INNER JOIN Sprint ON SprintTask.sprint_id = Sprint.Id WHERE Sprint.Id = @sid", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", Request.QueryString["sid"]);

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet st = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(st, "task_start_date");

    Chart1.DataSource = st.Tables["task_start_date"];
    Chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "task_start_date";
    Chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "hours_remaining";
    this.Chart1.Titles.Add("This is a test chart ");

    Chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    Chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
```

Comment: Please post your relevant code, sql, etc... you have the specific issues with. Also see  [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where applicable.

Comment: Show us the code where you are retrieving the data. This isn't hard to do but without knowing what data types you have, how you are retrieving the data, etc. its hard to know what to suggest.

Comment: @Chris more code added

Comment: Read up on `GROUP BY` and `SUM` for SQL Server.

Comment: You want "specific date", but how is that date stored: with or without time?

Comment: @HansKesting, it's stored without time

Answer (score 1):

As @mjwills wrote in his comment, you need to use group by and sum:

```
SELECT task_start_date, SUM(hours_remaining) As hours_remaining
FROM SprintTask 
INNER JOIN Sprint ON SprintTask.sprint_id = Sprint.Id 
GROUP BY task_start_date
WHERE Sprint.Id = @sid
```